# 301 redirect with/without trailing slash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx

How can I deal with this two conditions:

1) 301 Redirect root_url without slash to root_url with slash:

`https://example.com` -> `https://example.com/`

2) 301 Redirect for all other url`s with slash to url's without slash:

`https://example.com/about/` -> `https://example.com/about`

Second condition I resolve with this:

`rewrite ^(.+)/+$ $1 permanent;`

For first condition I think I can use:

`rewrite ^(.*[^/])$ $1/ permanent;`

But how to combine them without too many redirects exception?

Comment: ping  zolter!  is there anything still missing from my answer?  If yes, let me know, I'd be happy to provide any more info.  If no, I'd appreciate an upvote/accept.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot redirect from `example.com` to `example.com/`, because it's a special case where the trailing slash is always implied.

As such, this first case that you claim to be having trouble with, doesn't actually require any handling at all.